# Dynamically Updating Sidenav List Items

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a folder consisting of many html webpages. I added a sidenav to pages but I want the sidenav list items to populate dynamically (for ex: say title of each webpage should be added to the sidenav dynamically).

When I add a new webpage to this folder, I want the sidenav of all the webpages to contain the title of this new webpage in their list as well. Additionally, it will be obvious that on clicking those list items , we should be able to navigate to the desired webpages as well.

I think doing it manually for all the webpages is a bit teadious procedure.

Is it possible somehow programatically?

Comment: There are a thousand ways to make a sidenav. There are a thousand ways to arrange your webpages. That's one million ways to accomplish what you've described. TL;DR: show your code.

Comment: As javascript cannot read the filesystem, you will need some kind of backend. Or you could  just use a static site generator. Those have tools to accomplish this.

Comment: Yes, but you need server cooperation to do it, you won't be able to do it strictly from the browser.